# Use of torchvision.utils.save_image twice on the same image tensor makes the second save not work. What's going on?

Tags: image, image-processing, pytorch, tensor, torchvision

(Fast Gradient Sign Attack method detailed here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/fgsm_tutorial.html)

I have a trained classifier with >90% accuracy which I am using to create these adversarial examples, then I am using `torchvision.utils.save_image` to save the images to different folders.

The folder hierarchy is as follows:

- *FOLDER_1*

  - *original_image.jpg* **(1)**
  - *perturbed_image.jpg* **(2)**
- *FOLDER_2*

  - *perturbed_image.jpg* **(3)**

Here **(2)** and **(3)** are the same image tensor, which is the sum of the original image tensor and a perturbation image tensor---I just want to save images that fooled the classifier twice. What I'm finding is that **(1)** and **(2)** print O.K., but **(3)** only prints the perturbation image tensor (it subtracted the original image tensor!). So when I open up **(2)** I see my original picture with all the noise on top (random RGB pixel switches from the FGSM attack), but when I open up the **(3)** I see a blank canvas with those random RGB pixel switches ONLY.

Since I am printing the same variable (**perturbed_data**) twice, I don't understand why `torchvision.utils.save_image` is choosing to subtract the perturbation image tensor the second time I call it. The code for what I'm describing is below, and **data** is the original image tensor.

```py
epsilon = 0.5
# Collect datagrad
data_grad = data.grad.data

# Call FGSM Attack
perturbed_data = fgsm_attack(data, epsilon, data_grad)

# Re-classify the perturbed image
perturbed_output = model(perturbed_data)
perturbed_output = torch.sigmoid(perturbed_output)
perturbed_output = perturbed_output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
max_pred  = perturbed_output.item()
final_pred = torch.tensor([0, 0]).to(device)
final_pred[max_pred] = 1

# Store all original and perturbed images, regardless of model prediction
torchvision.utils.save_image(data, "./FOLDER_1/original.jpg")
torchvision.utils.save_image(perturbed_data, "./FOLDER_1/perturbed_image.jpg")

# If the perturbed image fools our classifier, put a copy of it in FOLDER_2
if !torch.all(torch.eq(final_pred, target)):
    torchvision.utils.save_image(perturbed_data, "./FOLDER_2/perturbed_image.jpg")
```

I'm almost sure that this is a torchvision bug, but I thought I would ask here before submitting a bug report. Maybe someone sees something I don't. I've also attached an example of **(2)** and **(3)** for visualization. The first image is in the correct format, but the second one prints without the original image tensor.

[image: original_img_tensor + pert_img_tensor]
[image: pert_img_tensor]

Comment: Maybe a typo there: `torchvision.utils.save_image(perturbed_data, "./../Data/perturbed_image.jpg")`, shouldn't the path be *"./../Data/FOLDER_2/perturbed_image.jpg"* ? Just making things consistent

Comment: Thanks for pointing them out! I've fixed the typos, but they are not the cause of the issue. I had to re-write the code to remove as much complexity as I could while keeping the issue reproducible.

Comment: I can't really test atm, but have you tested without the `if` condition ? If it still fails, that would mean the `save_image` affects your tensor. If not, that would mean the condition does it.

Comment: Thank you @Mat, you were correct. `save_image` was modifying the tensor.

Comment: Feel free to answer and accept your own question instead of editing, I don't mind it; just give me credit I suppose. I personally would check the internal code of `save_image` to see what changes the tensor, but that's not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `torchvision.utils.save_image` modifies the input tensor. A workaround to this is to add a line somewhere before calling `torchvision.utils.save_image` that's similar to this:

```py
perturbed_data_copy = perturbed_data
```

Then you can safely save the perturbed image twice if on the second call you use **perturbed_data_copy** instead of the **perturbed_data** (which was modified by torchvision.utils.save_image). I will be submitting a bug report and tagging this post. Thanks @Mat for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and it stemmed from `torchvision` only saving the second tensor. So I had two (image) tensors (image1 + image2) added together to form a new tensor (image3), but when I saved the new tensor (image3) a second time, it would save only as the second tensor (image2) in the sum.

PyTorch had a PR to fix this sometime late last year.